# I want to numerically integrate the function $1/(sqrt(1-y+x)*sqrt(y-x)$ with respect to x and plot the result with respect to y

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code but I'm not able to get that working.

```
def f(x,y):
    return 1/((np.sqrt(y-np.cos(x)))*(np.sqrt(1-y+np.cos(x))))

def Int(a,b,f,N):
    m=float(b-a)/N
    m>0 
    type(m)==int
    h=0.5*f(a,y)+0.5*f(b,y)
    for y>0 && y<2:
        for i in range(1,n):
            if y-np.cos(a+m*i)>0 and 1-y+np.cos(x)>0:
                h+=f(a+m*i,y)
            h*=m
            else:
                f==0
```

How to proceed further to get the plot.

Comment: `type(m) == int` is, unfortunately, totally useless. If you'd like to check whether `m` is of type `int` use `isinstance(m, int)`. `y>0 && y<2` is also incorrect. You should've used `and` instead of `&&` as `&&` is a syntax error. What's more, you aren't even trying to plot anything.

Comment: @ForceBru.. thanks for the edits. After that should I just make a list and store the values of h corresponding to y. and then plot?

Comment: I don't think this code will run and produce the results you need. See comment by ForceBru. `==` is a comparison, not an assignment. The last line `f==0` really does nothing then. You can simplify your `y>0 && y<2` into a more pythonic `0<y<2`. If you want to plot things I highly recommend looking into the [matplotlib library](http://matplotlib.org/).

Comment: @Luthor, frankly, you'd better learn some basics of Python first before approaching this task. You see, `m>0 `, `f==0` for example, are no-ops (useless operations) in this case. `m>0` is a mere comparison, that doesn't throw any error if `m` is less or equal to zero and `f==0` is an _equality check_, not an assignment. Also, `for y>0 && y<2` doesn't make sense even if you try not to look at the ampersands as you're trying to loop _over a boolean value_ here.